# Elastic Beanstalk configuration using ebextensions container_commands combining leader_only and test

Tags: bash, configuration, amazon-web-services, yaml

For our Django app running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, we use a web-server/worker setup. The same code is deployed to the web-server and worker environments, and environment-specific configuration is achieved with `.ebextensions` config files, using the `test` option for `container_commands`, among other things.

Now there are *some* container commands we would like to execute *only* during deployment or environment-creation (so we use `leader_only: true`, see bottom), but, *in addition*, they should never be executed on the worker environment.

The latter could be achieved using the `test` option, but that cannot be used not in combination with `leader_only`, according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands-options):

> ... A command can be leader-only or have a test, but not both (leader_only takes precedence).

Now, to work around this, we do something like the following, in `.ebextensions/foo.config`:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    ENV_NAME: '`{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`'  # get the current environment name

container_commands:
  0100_set_flag_if_instance_is_leader:
    command: touch /tmp/is_leader  # create empty file
    leader_only: true
  0200_execute_command_on_leader_only_but_never_on_worker:
    command: foo bar
    test: '[[ $ENV_NAME != "worker" && -e /tmp/is_leader ]]'
```

where `ENV_NAME` contains the environment name, which is automatically retrieved with the help of `option_settings` (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-optionsettings.html)).

Note that the config file is in `YAML` format and the commands and tests execute in a shell (I assume `bash`, since the extended test construct `[[` works, but could not find any specifics in the AWS docs).

As I am *not* an expert, I would really appreciate your comments on the following points:

1. The solution above works, but is this the simplest way to do it?
2. Are there any compelling reasons *not* to use this kind of set-up?
3. I tried setting a variable instead of creating a file (in command `0100`), but the variable does not appear to persist between container commands. Is there some way to achieve this? (I tried to `export`, but that didn't help. Is each container command executed in a separate shell, or how does this work?)

Some general background from the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands):

> You can use leader_only to only run the command on a single instance, or configure a test to only run the command when a test command evaluates to true. Leader-only container commands are only executed during environment creation and deployments, while other commands and server customization operations are performed every time an instance is provisioned or updated. Leader-only container commands are not executed due to launch configuration changes, such as a change in the AMI Id or instance type.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is an environment variable called `EB_IS_COMMAND_LEADER` which can be used in a test. See e.g. [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=224630) on AWS forums.

So, the two container commands from the OP can be replaced by this:

```
container_commands:
  0100_execute_command_on_leader_only_but_never_on_worker:
    command: foo bar
    test: '[[ $ENV_NAME != "worker" && $EB_IS_COMMAND_LEADER == "true" ]]'
```

I believe this environment variable is only available during deployment, although I could not find any documentation.

NOTE: The original question was aimed at Amazon Linux AMI (AL1), which is now deprecated. In the new [Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) we can use shell scripts in `.platform/hooks/` as an alternative to `container_commands`. The `EB_IS_COMMAND_LEADER` variable can be used there as well.